# Kernel Complie Error

Tags: compilation, linux-kernel, kernel

I am trying to compile A13 source kernel and I get this error any help would be appreciated.

**REF PAGE SOURCE:**

http://linux-sunxi.org/Linux

**COMMAND LINE BEING USED:**

At this point you can fine-tune your kernel configuration by running:

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- menuconfig
```

**ERROR:**

```
cripts/kconfig/lxdialog/menubox.o: In function `do_scroll':
menubox.c:(.text+0x55): undefined reference to `wrefresh'
scripts/kconfig/lxdialog/menubox.o: In function `print_arrows':
menubox.c:(.text+0x1a4): undefined reference to `wrefresh'
scripts/kconfig/lxdialog/menubox.o: In function `do_print_item':
menubox.c:(.text+0x3a9): undefined reference to `wrefresh'
scripts/kconfig/lxdialog/menubox.o: In function `print_buttons':
menubox.c:(.text+0x4b1): undefined reference to `wrefresh'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [scripts/kconfig/mconf] Error 1
make: *** [menuconfig] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You called the `menuconfig` target, which needs some dialog program to run. That program cannot be built because your `ncurses` library does not provide the `wrefresh` function.

On Ubuntu 12.04, try `sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5-dev`.

Other possible workarounds would be the use of `config` (text-driven), `xconfig` (QT-based) or `gconfig` (Gtk-based). If you already have a working configuration, `oldconfig` would also be an option.

Comment: Thank you for your answer so fast but the fix was adding the correct missing library which was "lib32ncurses5-dev"

P.S. I neglected mention my fault that this error is on Ubuntu 12.0.4

Regards, orbit